# "Such other people as are willing to do..." Sentence pattern

Tags: grammar, sentence-usage

In a 20th century speech I found the sentence:

> We are helping the people of our country and **such** other people **as** are our neighbors as well as **such** other people **as** are willing to receive help from us.

Here,

> **such..... as....**

Sentence pattern is new to me and I didn't find any information on this on internet.

Is the pattern **outdated** or **too formal to use use in daily life?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In the Cambridge online dictionary I found a link to [**Such** as a determiner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such) , where you will see examples of **such** meaning *of this or that kind*. I wouldn't call it outdated, but it is, as the website says, rather formal. We would probably say "Those people who are willing..." in everyday speech.

Comment: In practice, this is probably all the answer OP actually needs, so I've upvoted it accordingly. But there are other issues raised by the question, so I thought I'd better try to tackle them with an answer of my own.

Comment: It's perfectly good language but in the hands of politicians ... it tends to become a way of saying very little. In general the construct *such [X] as are [Y]* is a very precise way of defining a subset of X -- it's almost mathematical. Not usually *necessary*, but worth learning how to use.

Comment: Or to put it another way: it's a bit shorter than "the subset of [X] for which the predicate [Y] is true" :)

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence is ***very*** clumsy, because it uses ***such*** in close proximity *with two different meanings*. I'm guessing the intended sense could be paraphrased (*without* using ***such***) as...

> 1: *We [and other people, **for example**, our neighbors] are helping the people of our country [and we are also helping [those / some] other people **who are** willing to receive help from us].*

The essential problem here is that ***and*** such other people as **are** our neighbors is a noun phrase, that syntactically must represent an additional ***subject*** (of the verb ***helping***), not an additional ***object***. If we consider...

> 2: *Peter is helping Paul **and Mary***
>    3: *Peter **and Mary** are helping Paul*

...it should be obvious that the highlighted element in #2 extends the ***object*** (both Paul and Mary are being helped by Paul), whereas #3 extends the ***subject*** (both Peter and Mary are helping Paul). But because of the clumsy phrasing in OP's example, it's difficult to tell whether the speaker is helping his neighbours, or his neighbours are ***also*** helping "other people".

It's also difficult to tell whether the two different instances of "other people" refer to ***the same*** group of people. The "syntactic default" interpretation for the first instance is *people who are like the people of our country*, but the default for the second is *people who are willing to receive help from us*. Which doesn't make much sense to me.

---

TL;DR:
*I help **such people as** are here* is a formal / dated way of saying *I help **those people who** are here*, which is best avoided by learners. But note that the strong implication is I help ***only*** those people who are here.

BUT *I help **people such as** are here* is a different construction - also formal / dated, but *not so much as* the above. This second version unambiguously states that I help  *people who are **like** the people here* (usually with the strong implication that I ***also*** help the actual people who are here, but not necessarily<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, I might be a "special needs" teacher visiting a school in another district. Where if I say *I help **people such as** [those who] are here*, that doesn't mean I help the *actual* people at the other school - just that the people I ***do*** help are ***like*** them.

Comment: Same meaning, just slightly obscured by the placement of "other" before "such". It is clumsy in the sense that that language is unnecessary in this context (it is quite florid). Each "such ... as ..." specifies exactly what it says and there's no confusion at all. Just a big waste of space when it could say "ourselves, our neighbours and anyone [else] willing to accept support" :)

Comment: @WillCrawford: The specific category "ourselves, our neighbours and anyone [else] willing to accept support" certainly *doesn't* exist within OP's context. As I pointed out, it's somewhat unclear whether "our neighbours" are part of the group that *gives* help, or *receives* it. But obviously "ourselves" is part of the ***subject*** for ***to help***, whereas "anyone willing to accept support" is part of the ***object*** group, so they can't both be included in the same "noun phrase" here.

Answer (score 0):

Subject:

> - We°

Verb (auxiliary plus participle):

> - are helping

Object (actually a list of objects):

> - the people of our country¹
>
> and
>
> - such other people as are our neighbors²
>
> as well as
>
> - such other people as are willing to receive help from us³.

° From context, some representative of a government, charity or other public sector body.

¹ Literal neighbours, in the usual sense. In this case, presumably speaking on behalf of a democratically elected government, i.e. *as one of* the "people of our country", this means "ourselves"…

² …because "neighbours", if listed in addition to *people of our country*, now means *people of neighbouring [or otherwise nearby] countries*.

³ The *other* meaning this does not include those already covered as "people of our country" or "neighbours".